# how do I print a Yahoo email from within the Chrome browser?

Tags: printing

How do I print emails from Yahoo's email web application.  I am not using the browser's print capability.  I want to use the web application's print function.  I want to print to a PDF file.

When I click the print tool, nothing happens.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow pop-ups.  There will be a notification about a blocked pop-up in Chrome's URL text box on the right side.  Click it and allow pop-ups.